# 1 Iframe, 2 Sources - Combine Files for 1 Iframe

Tags: html, magento, iframe

I need to display 2 files in one iframe.  Currently, I have 2 iframes which isn't a good solution for my site.  I'd rather have 1 iframe that displays both files.

I am using this in a magento attribute so I don't think js will work without doing some development.  Any suggestions?

```
<iframe src="/path/to/file-001.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless" style="display:block; width:100%;  min-height:325px;"></iframe>
<iframe src="/path/to/file-002.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless" style="display:block; width:100%;  min-height:325px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using php to include file 2 at the bottom of file 1 and then just using file 1 in the iframe.

Comment: I would be interested in an alternative solution for this... how many files did you need to alter.  What if I had a few hundred files, this wouldn't be a feasible solution.  Thank you.